# SQL - Operar con variables distintas con distintos períodos de tiempo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Soy nuevo en ésto de SQL server y sus querys, y soy incapaz de resolver lo siguiente:

Tengo varias variables que registran datos con el tiempo:

| Variable | Personas | Tiempo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Calle1 | 11 | 2022-10-13 16:00:00.000 |
| Calle2 | 21 | 2022-10-13 16:00:00.000 |
| Calle3 | 31 | 2022-10-13 16:00:00.000 |
| Calle4 | 41 | 2022-10-14 16:00:00.000 |
| Calle1 | 12 | 2022-10-14 16:00:00.000 |
| Calle2 | 22 | 2022-10-14 16:00:00.000 |
| Calle3 | 32 | 2022-10-14 16:00:00.000 |
| Calle4 | 42 | 2022-10-14 16:00:00.000 |
| Calle1 | 13 | 2022-10-15 16:00:00.000 |
| Calle2 | 23 | 2022-10-15 16:00:00.000 |
| Calle3 | 33 | 2022-10-15 16:00:00.000 |
| Calle4 | 42 | 2022-10-15 16:00:00.000 |

Y lo que busco es hallar la relación entre el número de gente que pasa entre las calles 1, 2 y 3 respecto a la calle 4, en un tiempo de 2 días, de tal forma:

> (13+23+33-(11+21+31))/(42-41)

Lo que busco que me devuelva es leer un dato en el mismo formato (nombre as media, numero as porcentaje y tiempo as Tiempo), cuyo valor cambie según el tiempo que quiera consultar. No me es necesario escribirlo en otra tabla, solo poder consultarlo.

Lo cual me supera prácticamente al empezar.

He intentado aislar los distintos registros

```
SELECT top 3 Variable,
SUM(Personas),
Tiempo
FROM Tabla
WHERE Variable = 'Calle1' OR TAG = 'Calle2' OR TAG = 'Calle3'
GROUP BY Variable, Tiempo
ORDER BY Tiempo DESC
```

Lo que me devuelve los valores, pero no me los suma (de ahí el SUM). entiendo que si consigo operar esta suma, será análoga para el resto, aunque el tema de tiempos distintos es algo que no he conseguido aún solucionar.

He visto que la gente hace suma de varios select, tal que:

```
SELECT(
(SELECT top 1 Variable,
SUM(Personas),
Tiempo
FROM Tabla
WHERE Variable = 'Calle1', Tiempo = '2022-10-15 16:00:00.000'
GROUP BY Variable, Tiempo
ORDER BY Tiempo DESC)
+
SELECT(
(SELECT top 1 Variable,
SUM(Personas),
Tiempo
FROM Tabla
WHERE Variable = 'Calle2', Tiempo = '2022-10-15 16:00:00.000'
GROUP BY Variable, Tiempo
ORDER BY Tiempo DESC))
```

Para después sumar los valores del mismo tiempo. Hacer lo mismo con los valores del siguiente día, y restar ésto para conseguir el dividendo y divisor... pero creo que es demasiado rizar el rizo, y muy chapuza.

Como podeis ver, mucho lío y poco conocimiento. ¡Cualquier sugerencia es bien recibida! ¡Y muchas gracias por llegar hasta aquí!

Edit 1:

Tras la respuesta de @Javi fer2 (muchas gracias!) he estado trasteando e intentando aclarar cómo y qué quiero hacer.

Lo primero es explicar que las entradas de la tabla van añadiendo nuevos campos cada día que pasa, por lo que he cambiado la forma de coger los rangos de tiempo.

Por otro, una que no expliqué bien era que tenía que operar entre dos rangos distintos de tiempo, quitando el número de personas de cada calle de 2 días antes al contador que haya hoy (excluyendo en la cuenta lo que pase en el día de enmedio, y los días anteriores a estos). Mi idea, si funcionase, y siguiendo la respuesta de @Javi fer2 sería:

```
declare @1d datetime
set @1d = DATEADD(day,-1, GETDATE())
declare @2d datetime
set @2d = DATEADD(day,-2, GETDATE())
declare @3d datetime
set @3d = DATEADD(day,-3, GETDATE())

select (hoy.PersonasCalles123*1.0-d.PersonasCalles123*1.0) / (hoy.Resto*1.0-d.Resto*1.0) as VALOR
    From (
            select SUM(case variable when 'calle1' then personas
                                     when 'calle2' then personas 
                                     when 'calle3' then personas 
                        end
                        ) as PersonasCalles123,
                    max (case variable when 'calle4)' then personas AS Resto
            From misFechas 
            Where tiempo between @1d and GETDATE() 
) hoy;
    From (
            select SUM(case variable when 'calle1' then personas
                                     when 'calle2' then personas 
                                     when 'calle3' then personas 
                        end
                        ) as PersonasPersonasCalles123,
                    max (personas ) AS Resto
            From misFechas 
            Where tiempo between @3d and @2d
) d;
```

Mientras que el coger estos rangos de tiempo funcionan, no lo hace el poner los dos FROM de esta forma. He mirado y no estoy seguro si haciendo un JOIN serviría.

Por otro lado, la salida que me gustaría obtener sería de la sugiente forma:

| Columna | VALOR | TiempoHoy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RelacionCalle123RespectoA4 | 6 | 2022-10-13 16:00:00.000 (fecha de hoy) |

Lo he intentado añadiendo a lo anterior

```
...
select 
(hoy.PersonasCalles123*1.0-2d.PersonasCalles123*1.0) / (hoy.Resto*1.0-2d.Resto*1.0) as VALOR
Tiempo as TiempoHoy
From misFechas
...
```

Como si fuese una consulta a una tabla, pero no.

Siento todas las vueltas que estamos dando, gracias a todos los que me estáis ayudando, cuando lleguemos al final quitaré los edit y haré un resumen de los pasos que hemos ido haciendo

Comment: Para poder ayudarte es muy importante que pongas el escenario real. Y lo que esperas. Dices Tiempos y sumar....pero que tipos de datos son las columnas respectivas y que tipo de salida esperas?

Comment: Ya pero eso no es bastante, ¿Cual es la suma de los datetime?....Edita la pregunta, modifica el ejemplo. con lo que hay y lo que esperas obtener como resultado.

Comment: He borrado el anterior post y ampliado la información. Espero que quede más clara. Muchas gracias por echar un vistazo!

Comment: Y, ya leíste la documentación de las función [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)? O las demás [funciones de agregación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: He estado usando sobre todo las de max y min, y estaba trasteando con las SUM, pero al ver que no podía manejarlas fue cuando me decidí a preguntar, porque no vi en ningún foro una pregunta parecida. La respuesta de @Javi fer2 me acerca muchísimo a lo que busco, ahora le iba a responder.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque realmente no se exactamente lo que quieres conseguir, porque de lo que leo en el texto no me cuadra exactamente lo que veo en los ejemplos. Pero este puede ser un camino.

```
drop table if exists misFechas;
Create table misFechas (variable varchar(10), personas int, tiempo datetime)
Insert into misFechas(variable, personas, tiempo)
values
('Calle1',11,'20221013 16:00:00.000'),
('Calle2',21,'20221013 16:00:00.000'),
('Calle3',31,'20221013 16:00:00.000'),
('Calle4',41,'20221014 16:00:00.000'),
('Calle1',12,'20221014 16:00:00.000'),
('Calle2',22,'20221014 16:00:00.000'),
('Calle3',32,'20221014 16:00:00.000'),
('Calle4',42,'20221014 16:00:00.000'),
('Calle1',13,'20221015 16:00:00.000'),
('Calle2',23,'20221015 16:00:00.000'),
('Calle3',33,'20221015 16:00:00.000'),
('Calle4',42,'20221015 16:00:00.000');
```

Con el escenario que indicas.

Lo primero que puedes utilizar es la suma condicionada. Como no hay nada mejor que verlo.

```
select SUM(case variable when 'calle1' then personas 
                         when 'calle2' then personas 
                         when 'calle3' then personas 
            end
            ) as PersonasInCallesEspeciales,
        SUM (personas ) AS Total

From misFechas;
```

[image: Res1]

Utilizando un case, con una expresión puedes sumar solo cuando el registro encaja con la expresión a evaluar.

Luego aplicar un criterio, no tiene problema

```
select SUM(case variable when 'calle1' then personas
                         when 'calle2' then personas 
                         when 'calle3' then personas 
            end
            ) as PersonasInCallesEspeciales,
        SUM (personas ) AS Total

From misFechas 
Where tiempo >= '20221013' 
And tiempo < '20221015'
```

[image: res2]

Ahora hay que tener cuidado, porque eso devuelve números que cuando aplicas porcentajes, pueden no devolver el valor que esperas.

La solución es tán simple, como multiplicar el valor por 1.0 y así ya tienes un número con decimales que te permitirá hacer porcentajes.

```
select d.PersonasInCallesEspeciales*1.0 / d.Total*1.0
    From (
            select SUM(case variable when 'calle1' then personas
                                     when 'calle2' then personas 
                                     when 'calle3' then personas 
                        end
                        ) as PersonasInCallesEspeciales,
                    SUM (personas ) AS Total
            
            From misFechas 
            Where tiempo >= '20221013' 
            And tiempo < '20221015'
) d;
```

Dado que aunque has modificado la pregunta, no has expuesto la salida esperada real, no te puedo acercar más.

---

He cambiado los números de las variables, porque las fechas ya estaban insertadas.

Recuerda que null operacion mátematica operando, siempre es null.

Sin entrar a la formula que eso queda para tú terreno.
Cuando tienes una fila, y lo que quieres es añadir una columna a la fila, eso no es un join, porque no hay un identificador, para juntar filas, sino un cross join.

Por otro lado, eso que ves de una Select (expresion....), (expresión...), (expresión....), es una solución muy pobre en TSQL, con unos rendimientos málos. A veces el optimizador de consultas, que es muy listo, cambia eso por algo más usable y no te enteras....

```
declare @1d datetime
set @1d = DATEADD(day,-9, GETDATE())
declare @2d datetime
set @2d = DATEADD(day,-10, GETDATE())
declare @3d datetimE
set @3d = DATEADD(day,-11, GETDATE())

select (ISNULL(hoy.PersonasCalles123,0)*1.0-ISNULL(d.PersonasPersonasCalles123,0)*1.0) / (ISNULL(hoy.Resto,0)*1.0-ISNULL(d.Resto,0)*1.0) as VALOR
    From (
            select SUM(case variable when 'calle1' then personas
                                     when 'calle2' then personas 
                                     when 'calle3' then personas 
                        end
                        ) as PersonasCalles123,
                    max (case variable when 'calle4' then personas END) AS Resto
            From misFechas 
            Where tiempo between @1d and GETDATE() 
) hoy
    CROSS JOIN (
            select SUM(case variable when 'calle1' then personas
                                     when 'calle2' then personas 
                                     when 'calle3' then personas 
                        end
                        ) as PersonasPersonasCalles123,
                    max (personas ) AS Resto
            From misFechas 
            Where tiempo between @3d and @2d
    ) d
```

[image: Res1]

Así ya tienes un valor.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Javi fer2, la verdad es que me está ayudando mucho tus aportaciones. Es verdad que mi post puede quedar incompleto, te comento sobre lo que me has dicho cuales están siendo mis siguientes pasos en el edit 1, e intentar aclarar qué busco al final.